# I am having an error I cannot seem to fix on my microbit (line 55 type error 'none type' object is not subscriptable)

Tags: python, bbc-microbit

My code is for a game I am attempting to create, but the bottom of the code is continuously bringing up an error. I have left a copy of the code here, could you please help? The error is on line 55 [display.scroll ("You were slain...")]

```
from microbit import* 
import random
Character = []
Enemy = []
def RollDice():
    Diceroll1 = random.randint(1,6)
    Diceroll2 = random.randint(1,6)
    Total = Diceroll1 + Diceroll2
    return Total
def NewCharacter():
    Health = 100
    Strength = random.randint(30,80)
    Defence = random.randint(20,60)
    Character.append(Health)
    Character.append(Strength)
    Character.append(Defence)
    #display.scroll("You have 100 health, your strength is" + str(Strength) + " and you have" + str(Defence) + "defence.")
def NewEnemy():
    sleep(1000)
    MonsterTypes = ["Basilisk","Banshee","Behemoth"]
    Names = ["Ben","Bethany","Bobby", "Bella"]
    Enemy = []
    n1 = (random.choice(Names))
    n2 = (random.choice(MonsterTypes))
    Enemy.append(n1+ " the " +n2)
    Enemy.append(random.randint(30,70))
    Enemy.append(random.randint(35,70))
    Enemy.append(random.randint(25,70))
    return Enemy
def fight():
    Character = NewCharacter()
    while int(Character[0])>0:
        Enemy = NewEnemy()
        display.scroll (str(Enemy[0]) + "is here to fight!")
        while int(Enemy[1]>0) and int(Character[0])>0:
            display.scroll("A(Attack) or B(Block)")
            if button_a.is_pressed():
                Total = RollDice() + int(Character[1]) - int(Enemy[3])
                if Total < 1:
                    Total = 1
                Enemy[1] -= Total
                if int(Enemy[1]) < 0:
                    Enemy[1] = 0
                display.scroll (str(Enemy[0]) + "'s health is" + str(Enemy[1]) + ".")
                if int(Enemy[1]) < 1:
                    display.scroll ("You have slain" + str(Enemy[0]) + "!")
                else:
                    display.scroll (str(Enemy[0]) + "is attacking you!")
                    Total = RollDice() + int(Enemy[2]) - int(Character[2])
                    Character[0] -= Total
                    if int(Character[0]) < 0:
                        Character[0] = 0
                    display.scroll ("Your health is" + str(Character[0]) + ".")
                    if int(Character[0]) < 1:
                        display.scroll ("You were slain...")                       
fight()
```

Comment: If you get an error, you need to post it along with the full traceback.

Comment: line 55 type error 'none type' object is not subscriptable

Comment: No. That is not the full error or traceback.

Comment: It's on the micro:bit, that's all I am getting...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is located at the begging of your `fight()` function:

```
def fight():
    Character = NewCharacter()
    while int(Character[0])>0:
```

NewCharacter is a function that does not return anything, and so that's the same as doing:

```
def fight():
    Character = None
    while int(Character[0])>0:
```

You can just call the function `NewCharacter()` without saving the return value and then check the Character global.